# How to retrieve data from GPU? (Via SDI cable)

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, gpu, sdl-2

I have a camera that's connected to my GPU via SDI cable. I need somehow to capture live video information from that camera and be able to transfer it to SDL_Surface in my SDL2 program later (It would be enough to just get RGB of the pixels). The question is how should I do this or what other libraries should I use? Is something like FFmpeg is correct way to do this? Also maybe I should use another input from camera?

Comment: Your camera is not connected to your GPU, it's probably connected to a USB port or a capture card. To get access to its video frames you should either use a library (like FFmpeg) or DirectShow (I don't even know what OS you use). I suggest you do some more research.

Comment: Ok, I think thats capture card (which has SDI port), will do more research on FFmpeg and dshow, Im using Windows, thanks!